# How to use terminal commands on qt

Tags: qt, terminal, command

I am QT for a project and I want to compile and run few C++ codes on QT. I have written the following code to compile a C++ file. But I don't know how to check if the program was compiled properly. If once the program has compiled, how do I run it in a terminal?

The revised code:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionComplile_triggered()
{
    QProcess compile;
    compile.setWorkingDirectory("/home");
    compile.setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
    compile.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    QTextStream out(stdout);

    compile.start("gnome-terminal");
    compile.write("ls"); //these lines do not get printed.  

    compile.waitForReadyRead();
    compile.waitForFinished(-1);

    QByteArray msg = compile.readAll();
    out << msg.data() << endl;
}
```

Comment: QT != Qt.  Why haven't you followed the instructions in the `QProcess` docs for reading the output? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#communicating-via-channels

Comment: Sorry on the mistake I did. I have gone through them, I can compile the programs; I need help in writing to the terminal. When I try write("g++"); it does not display the commands on the terminal

Comment: I have revised the same code.Sorry I could not figure out how to upload it in a new thread for I am new here. It would be great help if you can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the Solution:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionComplile_triggered()
{
    QProcess compile;
    compile.setWorkingDirectory("/home/royal");
    compile.setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
    compile.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    QTextStream out(stdout);

    compile.start("g++",QStringList() << "tes.cpp" << "-o" << "test");
    compile.waitForFinished(-1);

    QByteArray msg = compile.readAllStandardOutput();
    if(msg.isEmpty())
    {
        qDebug() << "Successful";
    }
    else qDebug() << "Failed";
}
```